# d3 join on object key within array

Tags: d3.js

My data looks like this:

```
[
   {
      name: "Joel Spolsky",
      values: [
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432214730,
                   value: 55
                },
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432215730,
                   value: 32
                },   
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432216730,
                   value: 2
                },   
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432217730,
                   value: 37
                },

                // etc
              ]     
    },
   {
      name: "Soul Jalopy",
      values: [
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432214730,
                   value: 35
                },
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432215730,
                   value: 72
                },   
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432216730,
                   value: 23
                },   
                {
                   timestamp: 1380432217730,
                   value: 3
                },

                // etc
              ]     
    },

    // and so on
]
```

I pass this data into `d3.layout.stack` so a `y` and `y0` get added. I then draw this stacked layout.

When the data changes, I join the new data to the old.

I can join the groups on `name` like this:

```
var nameGroups = this.chartBody.selectAll(".nameGroup")
        .data(this.layers, function (d) {
                return d.name;
             });
```

But I'm having trouble joining the rectangles (or "bars") on timestamp. The best I can do (so far) is join them on the `values` key:

```
var rects = nameGroups.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
                return d.values;
              });
```

How do I join this "inner data" on the `timestamp` key?

I've tried including the array index:

```
var rects = nameGroups.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d, i) {
                return d.values[i].timestamp;
              });
```

But that doesn't work because (I think) the timestamp is matched per array index. That is, the join isn't looking at all timestamp values for a match, just the one at that index.

UPDATE

Here is my complete update function:

```
updateChart: function (data) {
    var that = this,
        histogramContainer = d3.select(".histogram-container"),
        histogramContainerWidth = parseInt(histogramContainer.style('width'), 10),
        histogramContainerHeight = parseInt(histogramContainer.style('height'), 10),
        width = histogramContainerWidth,
        height = histogramContainerHeight,
        nameGroups, rects;

    /*
     FWIW, here's my stack function created within my
     init function:

     this.stack = d3.layout.stack()
         .values(function (d) { return d.values; })
         .x(function (dd) { return dd.timestamp; })
         .y(function (dd) { return dd.value; });

     */

    // save the new data
    this.layers = this.stack(data);

    // join the new data to the old via the "name" key
    nameGroups = this.chartBody.selectAll(".nameGroup")
        .data(this.layers, function (d, i) {
            return d.name;
        });

    // UPDATE
    nameGroups.transition()
        .duration(750);

    // ENTER
    nameGroups.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "nameGroup")
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {
            //console.log("entering a namegroup: ", d.name);
            var color = (that.colors[d.name]) ?
                    that.colors[d.name].value :
                    Moonshadow.helpers.rw5(d.name);
            return "#" + color;
        });

    // EXIT
    nameGroups.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
        .remove();

    rects = nameGroups.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {

            // I think that this is where the change needs to happen

            return d.values;

        });

    // UPDATE
    rects.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return that.xScale(d.timestamp);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return -that.yScale(d.y0) - that.yScale(d.y);
        })
        .attr("width", this.barWidth)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return +that.yScale(d.y);
        });

    // ENTER 

    rects.enter().append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", "stackedBar")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return that.xScale(d.timestamp); })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return -that.yScale(d.y0) - that.yScale(d.y); })
        .attr("width", this.barWidth)
        .attr("height",function (d) {
            return +that.yScale(d.y); })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
        .transition()
        .duration(1250)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // EXIT

    rects.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .remove();
}
```

Comment: That would be something like `d.values[0].timestamp`, no?

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't it need to be something like d.values[i].timestamp? So that it's joining each rect's `timestamp` and not just the first one?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Could you show us the complete code please? I'm not quite sure where you're trying to do this matching.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - I've done some more work and updated the question

Comment: Oh hang on, you're not actually passing a key function there. Try `.data(function(d) { return d.values; }, function(d) { return d.timestamp; })`.

Comment: Wow! @LarsKotthoff, that's fantastic! Where, praytell, did you find that syntax? I looked for quite a long time but couldn't find anything.  (Also, make it the answer so I can credit you, if you'd like).

Comment: Well the key function is the second argument and you were passing only one. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Now that it's obvious, of course. The 2nd argument. And the docs state it precisely. I suppose the issue is that in scanning literally hundreds of examples/blocks, I had never seen two functions passed to the call to data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually passing a key function in your code. The key function is the optional second argument to `.data()` (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data)). So in your case, the code should be

```
.data(function(d) { return d.values; },
      function(d) { return d.timestamp; })
```

Here the first function tells D3 how to extract the values from the upper level of the nesting and the second how, for each item in the array extracted in the first argument, get the key.